# Can't get localization to work on iOS app

Tags: xcode, ios6, localization, xcode4.6, localizable.strings

I just cannot get this to work. No matter what I do, the call to `NSLocalizedString` *always* returns the key I pass into it.

I've read every answer to every question on here and none of them have any effect. I've cleaned, rebuilt, reinstalled.

I have a file called `Localizable.strings` that I created in Xcode, using the new file wizard and selected "Strings file" as the template. I added two key/value pairs. I clicked the "Localize" button in the inspector and added English. Heck I even tried adding a new Copy build phase to the project like one answer suggested. I've opened the package and verified that there is an en.lproj folder with my correct `Localizable.strings` file in it.

But when I call `NSLocalizedString` and pass it one of my keys (which I've copy-pasted to make sure it's exactly identical), it just returns the key no matter *what* I do. I've even tried calling `NSLocalizedStringFromTable` and passing it "Localizable.strings" as the table name, but nothing.

I'm losing my mind. Why is this so hard?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see : in your strings file, it should be = . 
For instance

```
/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Username"="nom d'utilisateur";
```

Comment: Omg thank you, why on earth would the compiler not tell me that was wrong...?

Comment: You are welcome :) .Strings file is a simply file, is not compiled or analized is part of resources, localization is always a mess on ios. I use the software Linguan from cocoanetics to be more productive.

Comment: Because strings files are not compiled? ;-)

Comment: Well some kind of syntax parsing would sure have helped. :P